# Flask template render and return

Tags: python, flask

I am using a simple template rendering using flask. At the same time, I am using flask as an endpoint for chatbot.

An extract from main.py:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, render_template, make_response
import urllib
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
  req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)

  res = makeWebhookResult(req)

  res = json.dumps(res, indent=4)
  r = make_response(res)
  r.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
  return r

def makeWebhookResult(req):
  url_prod="picture.jpg"
  if req.get("result").get("action") == "action.prod":
    result = req.get("result")
    parameters = result.get("parameters")
    prod = parameters.get("products")
    speech = "what I want to say is...  " + prod
    render_template('hello.html', name=url_prod)
  else:
    return {}

  return {
    "speech": speech,
    "displayText": speech,
    "source": "apiai-demo"
  }
```

my hello.html:

```
<body>
  <iframe
  width="350"
  height="430"
  src="https://xxxxxx"
</iframe>
<img src={{name}}>
</body>
```

My problem is that for the endpoint, I need to return json data, and at the same time I would like to update the template of the html file. As the render_template is not in the return function, the direct call  render_template('hello.html', name=url_pic1) does not work . 
How to call the render_template and at the same time allow flask to return the json reply? Hope I am clear. Thanks

Comment: I am afraid your endpoint can return only one content-type at a time.

Comment: too bad... Any other ways to dinamically update html file maybe with another library?